# Segoe UI license needed?

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-face

I have a new website and I was wondering about the license specifics regarding Segoe UI, a font Microsoft uses on lots of stuff.  Do I need a license if I use the font in any way on a website, or do I only need a license if I use in in a @font-face manner?  If so, what is a cheap way to get a license/how can I get one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official answer](http://www.ascendercorp.com/font/segoe-ui/) is,

> Please fill out the form below to contact Monotype Imaging regarding our various font license extensions for multiple workstations, servers or enterprise-wide applications. We will respond promptly to all inquiries. Thank you.

They do mention the usage on web server explicitly, so I'd ask first and took it from there.

**Update:** That is, regardless of the answer you can get here, they are the copyright holders, and even if you have a trick to get around them, it's safer and easier to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft publishes the Segoe WP font family under the Apache license as part of the [LightSwitch Metro Theme Extension Sample for Visual Studio 11](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/LightSwitch-Metro-Theme-7424397b). The fonts are stored in the folder `C#\MetroThemeExtension\MetroThemeExtension.Client\Presentation\Fonts`.

**Update**: The 6/19/2012 update to the sample removed the `Fonts` folder.